# Alternatives to Inflector.Net

Tags: c#, .net, inflector

I want to use inflector.net in my project.

Just googled and it seems to have gone. :-<

http://andrewpeters.net/inflectornet/

Are there any alternatives?

---

**EDIT (11 May 2011):** It looks like Scott Kirkland has taken up the baton:

https://github.com/srkirkland/Inflector

(Thanks Scott!)

Comment: And what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Jennifer Zouak That's irrelevant.

Comment: @Catalin it's a port of the rail inflector - does lots of useful string manipulation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Inflector.html

Comment: Does anyone know what the license is for this? I can't see any license info at https://github.com/srkirkland/Inflector

Comment: @muzzamo Good point. As abandonware it's difficult to say. However, as the software is a port of the rails inflector, would it would be reasonable to use the same license?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Google code search for "Inflector.Net" returned this one:

http://cid-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Cid.Mvc/Inflector.cs

Answer (score 3):

http://cid-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Cid.Mvc/Inflector.cs

used to make https://github.com/markrendle/Inflector

which 
 is available via a NuGet Package last updated today!

`package id="Inflector" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45"`

Answer (score 2):

Some of that code seems to be included in the NCommon project. Take a look at http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/

Answer (score 1):

Inflector is also integrated into Caliburn (http://caliburn.codeplex.com) in namespace Caliburn.Core