# Can I use linq's method of pluralizing a term?

Tags: c#, linq, pluralize

In .net 3.5 if I generate a linq to sql data context, it does some wonderful magic to pluralize names.  In my code I need to pluralize some terms.  Can I use whatever method Linq is using to generate my plurals?

Comment: Dunno about 3.5 but if I were targeting 4 I'd check out EF4's [PluralizationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.createservice.aspx)

Comment: Bummer. I am stuck on 3.5 for the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL doesn't expose its pluralization logic. A quick check with Reflector reveals that it's not using a terribly complex algorithm though:

> If it ends with 'x', 'ch', 'sh' or 'ss', then add 'es'.
>   If it ends with 'y' preceded by a consonant, remove the y and add 'ies'.
>   Otherwise, add 's'.

If .NET 4 is an option, then EF's PluralizationService is much more thorough. Just in case you ever need to pluralize 'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis'.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use reflector to dig into the visual studio assemblies that do the code generation for the linq-to-sql designer.

Comment: thought I'd get a freebie since you were a moderator and it was in a comment =)

Answer (score 2):

There's also a .NET port of Inflector which does the same job. The author's blog is now down but it's available at http://cid-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Cid.Mvc/Inflector.cs amongst others.

(via [Alternatives to Inflector.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552816/alternatives-to-inflector-net/2553071#2553071))

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL uses a fairly simple system for pluralization. If you are going to be working with complex terms, I recommend you **use something like [the Inflector that is part of SEDE](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/Inflector.cs)**. That piece of code seems to originate from the [SubSonic project](http://subsonicproject.com/).

Comment: Inflector is not part of subsonic that seems to be a grievously incorrect attribution. It was written by Andrew Peters as a port from the ruby inflector. His site is no longer available however his code is accessible still at: http://cid-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Cid.Mvc/Inflector.cs  and correctly has his copyright notice included.

Comment: Actually, I'd say that the version in subsonic is an independent port of the Rails version, since they make different decisions about how to name things after porting.

Comment: @stevemegson that's true, the names are different. However, it seems that subsonic took Andrew's version, renamed all of the methods, and added brief XML documentation.